# render() is not getting invoked while setState is getting call from test class?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactive-programming

Suppose there is component class with handleCloseEvent() and render() method.
handleCloseEvent() changes data in state object using this.setState.

From test class, component is mounted before run on of any test and unmounted in after test method. From one of test method, handleCloseEvent is getting called using "page.instance().setState({})".
Render is not getting call on invocation of handleCloseEvent from unit test class.
Please help me in fixing this.

```
class DropdownList extends React.Component { 
     ......
     ......
     ......
     handleCloseEvent() {
         this.setState({
            x: null
         });
     }
     .........
     .........
     .........
     .........
     render() {
        return (
           <div class={`${!this.state.x ? "hidden" : ""}`>
           </div>
        );
     }
}


describe("Component: DropdownList", () => {
   it("Checking render", () => {
        page = intlHelper.mountWithIntlWithoutRelay(<DropdownList dropdownStore={dropdownStore} onAddItem={handleAddRemoveDrodownItemSpy} onRemoveItem={handleAddRemoveDrodownItemSpy}/>);
        page.instance().handleCloseEvent();
        expect(page.find(".hidden").props().show).to.be.true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Show us the relevant code that represents your issue.

Comment: It's 17 mins and you din't provide the details. So, voting to close.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Added sample code